# char arr = "..."; in C program leads to crash

Tags: c, arrays, string

im a beginner and my english is not so well so sorry first. i wrote a function that gets a string and a number, and move every letter in the string 'number' steps. i tried to debug it and it stop working. anyone knows the problem?

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void moveString(char* str, int _switch);

void main()
{
    char arr = "abcdef";
    moveString(arr, 2);
    printf("%s", arr);
}

void moveString(char* str, int _switch)
{
    int len = strlen(str) + 1, i = 0, j = 0, move = len - _switch + 1;
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
    if (!temp)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0;i < move;i++)
        temp[i+_switch] = str[i];
    for (j = 0;j < _switch;j++)
        temp[j] = str[len - _switch + j + 1];
    str = temp;
}
```

here is the error:

> Exception thrown at 0x0FCA1FD0 (ucrtbased char arr = ".dll) in
>   ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x00000030."

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. You have `return NULL` in a function declared as returning `void`.

Comment: You're writing to `temp[i+_switch]`. The value of `i` is at most `move - 1`. `move` is `len - _switch + 1`, so the maximum value of `i` is `len - _switch`. Therefore the maximum value of `i+_switch` is `len`. `temp` is `len` bytes long, so the index `len` is out of bounds (valid indices are `0` .. `len-1`).

Comment: `str` is a local variable in `moveString`. The assignment `str = temp` is useless because it's "dead": It's the last statement in the function before `str` ceases to exist, so no one is ever going to see the assigned value.

Comment: `temp` is never freed. That's a memory leak.

Comment: `main` should return `int`, not `void`. Don't cast `malloc()`.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: Any "warning" that you get from a C compiler is usually a *serious error*.

Comment: thank you all for your comments. ill check it again:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pay attention to the compiler warnings and eliminate of all them. They exist for a reason.

When you complie your code, you are most probably getting something like `warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] char arr = "abcdef";` which is the reason for your crash.

It should be `char *arr = "abcdef"`, because `"abcdef"` in C is a *pointer* to the area of memory where `abcdef` is written.

But that's not the only problem with your program. Seriously, look at the compiler messages and make sure you understand what are the warnings, and fix your code not to produce any.

Comment: That's a bunch of comments with general advice, but not an answer.

Comment: @Olaf This is the answer. Read carefully. As said in it, changing `char arr` to `char *arr` will eliminate the crash.